# Performing actions while iterating over a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am iterating over a list

```
xxx
yyy
**start word**
xxx
yyy
zzz
**stop word** 
break
```

I need to append to another list all the data between start and stop words, how do I do that?

The stop word appears couple times in the list. So the appending should be stopped when loop finds first stop word on it's way.

For example:

```
list = [1,2,3 ... 1000]
new_list = []
for i in list:
    # Once i = 5 I need to start appending i values to new_list until i = 25.
```

Comment: Could you show us your code so far?  It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a boolean to indicate when to start appending and when to stop appending. For this, you could write your code something like -

```
old_list = ['axz','bbbdd','ccc','start','Hello World','Bye','end','ezy','foo']
another_list=[]

append_to_list = False     # Boolean to indicate if we should append current element
start_word = 'start'
end_word = 'end'
for element in old_list:
    if element == end_word :
        append_to_list = False
    if append_to_list :    # Appending to list if the Boolean is set
        another_list.append(element)
    if element == start_word :
        append_to_list = True


print(another_list)
```

**Output :**

```
['Hello World', 'Bye']
```

Here, `start` and `end` are the start and stop words, you could modify them as per your start and stop words of the program.

---

Another possible solution would be to fetch the index of your start and stop words and just store the elements between those indexes into your `another_list` as follows -

```
old_list = ['axz','bbbdd','ccc','start','Hello World','Bye','end','ezy','foo']

start_idx = old_list .index("start")
stop_idx = old_list .index("end")

another_list = old_list[start_idx+1:stop_idx]

print(another_list)
```

**Output :**

```
['Hello World', 'Bye']
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: The second solution is basically a fixed version of Nathan's solution.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa That's right ! His version was adding a list into the list as well as using the starting element too which wasn't OP's intent. So I added the correct version into my answer

Comment: The first version it's exactly what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would be great to get more information, but from what you've provided, you could use the index of your "start" and "stop" words to append to a new list:

```
list1 = ["xxx", "yyy", "start_word", "xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "end_word"]

a = list1.index("start_word")
b = list1.index("end_word")

list2 = []
list2.append(list1[a:b])

print(list2)
```

#### Output :

```
[['start_word', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']]
```

Comment: You should use `list.extend` to get rid of the unnecessary extra list. If you append a list slice it will append a list, not the individual elements of the list. On the other hand, you could just use the sliced list directly, it already is the list of the wanted elements, if you add `+1` to the start index.

Comment: @NathanThomas thanks, great solutions, it almost solves my problem, but this stop word might appear earlier in list, so I need program to start recording it after start word and stop after the first stop word in the list. My bad for not providing you with that piece of information, thanks you, good point!